# How do you do a cross product of two $3 \times 3$ boolean matrices?

Tags: matrices, computer-science

I have two boolean matrices:

```
A = |1 1 0|
    |0 1 0|
    |0 0 1|

and

B = |1 0 0|
    |1 1 1|
    |0 0 1|
```

What is the result of **A x B** and what are the steps needed to attain the result?

**Note:** My textbook says that the answer to the above is:

```
A x B = |1 1 1|
        |1 1 1|
        |0 0 1|
```

and that **`A * B`** is not equal to **`A x B`**. Unfortunately, it does not give the steps needed to find the solution.

Comment: It looks like you're being asked for a matrix product, not a cross product.

Comment: My source specifically states that A*b is not equal to AxB. Unfortunately, it does not provide one single example.

Comment: See edited question above

Comment: Does it provide a definition or not? That is very strange.

Comment: It doesn't. The book is a programming book assuming we know this math already.

Comment: Well, if we interpret + to mean "or" rather than "xor", then it seems to agree with the usual definition of matrix multiplication...

Comment: What do you mean exactly? If you know the answer, can you post it so I can approve it?

Comment: Now I wonder what $A * B$ is supposed to mean...

Comment: It means "A dot B"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is the same as conventional matrix multiplication just that the multiplication is replaced by the "and" operation while the addition is replaced by the "or" operation.

Hence, $$A \times B = 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$A \times B = \begin{bmatrix} (1 \& 1) || (1 \& 1) || (0 \& 0) & (1 \& 0) || (1 \& 1) || (0 \& 0) & (1 \& 0) || (1 \& 1) || (0 \& 1) \\\ (0 \& 1) || (1 \& 1) || (0 \& 0) & (0 \& 0) || (1 \& 1) || (0 \& 0) & (0 \& 0) || (1 \& 1) || (0 \& 1) \\\ (0 \& 1) || (0 \& 1) || (1 \& 0) & (0 \& 0) || (0 \& 1) || (1 \& 0) & (0 \& 0) || (0 \& 1) || (1 \& 1) \end{bmatrix}$$

$$A \times B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: i think the final result in the table is not correct.it should be $2$ at position (1,1)

Comment: http://matrix.reshish.com/multCalculation.php